# angular disable apply button if none of the div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

The requirement is simple. I have to enable the **Apply** button only if atleast one of the div is selected to green. Suggest some idea please.. Have given the running snippet below for reference. Thanks!

```css
.aw-right-pane-content{height:200px; width:200px;}
.aw-dataType-selected{background:green;}

.charts{
  height:30px; width:30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
  margin:20px 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" 
     ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false},{name:'Chart3',selected:false},{name:'Chart4',selected:false}]">
       <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts" >
          <div ng-click="chart.selected = !chart.selected" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}"></div>
          <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}}</div>
        </div>
<button disabled>Apply</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `ng-disabled` like `<button ng-disabled="expression">Apply</button>`

Comment: Thanks Hemakumar.. Am actually looking for that expression only.. Could you please execute your solution the snippet and let me know pls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, have a property that keeps track of the selected divs and have ng-disabled on that property, in the example is selectionCount.

```css
.aw-right-pane-content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.aw-dataType-selected {
  background: green;
}
.charts {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="aw-right-pane-content" ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false},{name:'Chart3',selected:false},{name:'Chart4',selected:false}]">
    <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts" ng-init="$parent.selectionCount = 0">
      <div ng-click="chart.selected = !chart.selected; $parent.selectionCount = (chart.selected == true ? $parent.selectionCount+1 : $parent.selectionCount-1)" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}"></div>
      <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name">{{chart.name}}</div>
    </div>
    {{selection}}
    <button ng-disabled="selectionCount == 0">Apply</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sreekanth, that's cool.. Thanks a lot. :) Timely help.. This is what am expecting.. I even have a side menu, each option in which has a set of chart divs.. selecting any one from any option should enable Apply.. your $parent, solves my requirement.. :)

Comment: @Sreekanth really nice answer.... I didn't get this Idea... It helped... :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.aw-right-pane-content{height:200px; width:200px;}
.aw-dataType-selected{background:green;}

.charts{
  height:30px; width:30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
  margin:20px 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" 
     ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false},{name:'Chart3',selected:false},{name:'Chart4',selected:false}]">
       <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts" >
          <div ng-click="chart.selected = !chart.selected" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}"></div>
          <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}}</div>
        </div>
<button ng-disabled="(chartsOfSelectedDatatype | filter:{ selected: true }).length == 0">Apply</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot J-Mean :)

Comment: Welcome :) Suresh